# Why is my attempt to replace a character in a string failing?

Tags: php, regex, character-encoding

I have a string (taken from a MySQL database if it makes any difference) which looks normal enough:

```
Manufacture: <a href="http://www.x.com/">Blah</a>
```

The problem is that the space between `Manufacture:` and the `<a>` tag has a charcode of 194, not 32 as I would expect.

This is causing a `preg_match` with the following pattern to fail (please ignore the attempts to parse HTML with regex, I know it's not a good idea but this particular dataset is predictable enough to get away with it):

```
/Manufacture: *(<a[^>]*>([A-Za-z- 0-9]+)<\/a>)/i
```

If I replace the rogue space with a normal space character in a text editor and try again, the expression matches as expected, but I need to alter it programatically.

I tried `str_replace`:

```
$text = str_replace(chr(194), ' ', $text);
```

But the `preg_match` still fails. I then tried `preg_replace`:

```
$text = preg_replace('/[\xC2]/', ' ', $text);
```

But that doesn't work either, even though running that same pattern through `preg_match` *does* contain the expected match.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it's codepoint 194? That should be a "capital letter A with circumflex" `Â` and not a spacing character.

Comment: @user1515834 Positive, I copied the character onto the clipboard and ran it through `ord()`, which returns 194. Also `preg_match('/[\xC2]/', $text);` returns `TRUE`, confirming that character is definitely in there (C2 being 194 in hex)

Comment: So it should be the capital A with circumflex, surely? Why is it appearing as a space for you?

Comment: I agree, how do you know that the character is a decimal 194?  Did you `sprintf( "character %d is \"%d\"", $i, $text[$i] )` each character of the string?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Please see my previous comment, I've confirmed it with 2 methods

Comment: @user1515834 That's what I would expect too, but it's not the case. No idea why

Comment: Maybe I'm using the wrong source, but isn't ASCII character decimal 194  the box drawing character that looks like a capital [T](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-codes/box-drawing-character-ascii-code-194.gif)?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn Now that you mention it yes, the `Â` character would be unicode 194 I think

Comment: If the string always starts with "Manufacture:", perhaps you could just discard the first 13 characters (length of "Manufacture:" + the mysterious character), and just run your regex on the remaining string.

Comment: @EyalAr It's actually buried deep in another string but thanks for the idea

Comment: @Clive, Can you match something after the <a> instead of before it?

Comment: I'm guessing you are looking at the beginning of a UTF-8 sequence, quite possibly U+00A0 whose UTF-8 encoding is 194 160 (0xC2 0xA0). http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/a0/index.htm

Comment: @HeatfanJohn "ASCII" ends at character code 127, the meaning of 194 in various 8-bit encodings obviously depends on the encoding. Box-drawing characters mainly exist in ancient DOS legacy code pages.

Comment: @tripleee Yes, I agree.  The source I used was incorrect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you please check the structure of the MySQL table where you get the contents of $text from?  If the collation is `utf8_general_ci` or something like that then your string most likely contains a double-byte UNICODE character.

[image]

If that is the case then the PHP function [iconv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) should do the trick.  Here's the example from the PHP manual.  The `IGNORE` option should remove the UNICODE character from the string.

```
<?php
$text = "This is the Euro symbol '€'.";

echo 'Original : ', $text, PHP_EOL;
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//IGNORE", $text), PHP_EOL;
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text), PHP_EOL;

?>
```

**The above example will output something similar to:**

```
Original : This is the Euro symbol '€'.
TRANSLIT : This is the Euro symbol 'EUR'.
IGNORE   : This is the Euro symbol ''.
Plain    :
Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in .\iconv-example.php on line 7
This is the Euro symbol '
```

Comment: Brilliant that must have been the problem, using the `IGNORE` option with `iconv` worked a treat. Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

what if you try to match *any* whitespace character?
like so:

```
/Manufacture:\s*(<a[^>]*>([A-Za-z- 0-9]+)<\/a>)/i
```

Comment: How about using "." (any character)?  I could be way off base, but does PHP use UTF-8 character encoding?  Namely could this character be a double byte UNICODE character?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn That's looking more and more likely, thanks for the pointer...not to betray my ignorance in this subject too much (!) but would you know how I can replace that unicode character with a space in PHP?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn By the way trying `.*` doesn't work either (nor does `[^<]*`) which is making me even more confused